# DateTime object always contain minute as 05 after converting from TimeOfDay in flutter

Tags: datetime, flutter, timepicker

I using TimePicker for getting start time and end time. I'm using DateTime object in my data model. 
converting TimeOfDay to DateTime like this

```
  DateTime newTime = new DateTime(
                              startTime.year,
                              startTime.month,
                              startTime.day,
                              picked.hour,
                              picked.minute);
```

I print using this formmater

```
DateFormat timeFormat = new DateFormat("hh:mm a");
```

but newTime always contain minute as 05.
DateTime.now() also print minute as 05 like 12:05 PM.

Comment: DateTime newTime = DateTime(2020,5,8,12,32);
print(newTime); // output: 2020-05-08 12:32:00.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to print using the wrong DateFormatter

using

```
DateFormat timeFormat = new DateFormat("hh:mm a");
```

instead of

```
DateFormat timeFormat = new DateFormat.jm();
```